# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in WordPress 4.9.8

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to run this codes in WordPress 4.9.8 but am getting an error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in WordPress 4.9.8

```
<?php
        // Create an array for post title
        $post_title = [
            "Hello World",
            "Hello PHP",
            "Hello WordPress"
        ];

        //Loop through array of post

        foreach ( $post_titles as $post_title){

            // Call the $display_title title functions and pass it the post title

            display_title ( $post_title);
        }

        /* Display the title for a post
        *
        * @param string $title the title to be displayed
        */

        function display_title( $title){
            // Echo an h3 tag with the title inside

            echo "<h3>". $title ."</h3>";
        }


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently trying to loop through an array that does not exist.

Instead of assigning your array the variable of:

```
$post_title
```

You should assign it as:

```
$post_titles
```

From there you can loop through your array by calling your variable as new variable.
You are currently trying to echo out your array variable instead of echoing out each title. Updated code below.

```
<?php 
    // Create an array for post title 
    $post_titles = [ "Hello World", "Hello PHP", "Hello WordPress" ]; 
    //Loop through array of post 
    foreach ( $post_titles as $title){ 
       echo "<h3>". $title ."</h3>"; 
    } 
?>
```

If you are simply trying to get the title of a post in your query loop, you can use:

```
the_title()
```

More info on WordPress titles here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title